# Trigger Plugin from model - Joomla

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I created a custom plugin for my joomla extension, it all works well while trying to trigger it from a template override (just for test).
But when I try to fire it from the extension model (the same code that works in the override) it doesn't trigger the event.

Is there anything specific that needs to be done to the extension to be able to trigger it from the model?

here is what I am using and works in the template override but doesn't work in the model

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('bookingnotification');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onHelloWorld', array());
```

I am clueless

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to own my question.
For some reason if I am triggering the event from a template override I can specify only the plugin folder in the importPlugin, like below

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('bookingnotification');
```

But if I am triggering it from the model it will only work (or at least in my case) if I specify the the group and the plugin folders, like below

```
 JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user','bookingnotification');
```

I hope this helps some else